# Zsh executing two commands in a row independent of success

Tags: command-line, zsh

I would like to execute two commands in a row independent of the failure or success of the previous one, so I know that `||` and `&&` will not work. What can I do in this case? I would like to have the shell wait for the first command to finish if it is successful; hence `;` does not work either.

EDIT: I apologize the shell would be `zsh` and I run a shell script sending commands to different screens as seen below:

```
#! /bin/zsh
### Script for running everything in screens ###
### System argument screen name suffix ###
echo You have the following screens running:
screen -ls
sigarr=(NM1 NM2 NM3 Scenario4 Scenario6)
puarr=(50PU 140PU)
lumarr=(30 300 3000)
echo Please type 1 for 50PU samples and 2 for 140PU samples
read PU
if [[ $PU -ne 1 && $PU -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo You have to enter 1 or 2
    return 1
fi

echo Please type 1 for 300fb-1 and 2 for 3000fb-1
read lum

if [[ $lum -ne 1 && $lum -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo You have to enter 1 or 2
    return 1
fi

if [ $PU = 1 ]; then
    let "lum = $lum + 1"
    #echo $lum
fi

ex NEWrunReader.py  <<EOEX
  :43s/Lumi.*/Lumi=$lumarr[lum]/
  :x
EOEX

echo Compiling the reader file!!!
root -l << EOF
.L readerSummerStd.C+
EOF

if [ $PU = 2]; then
    let "lum = $lum + 1"
fi

echo Press any key to proceed or Ctrl+C to abort!
read 


for sigind in $sigarr
do
    screen -dmS "${sigind}_${lumarr[lum]}_${puarr[PU]}_${1}" 
    sleep 0.1
    screen -S "${sigind}_${lumarr[lum]}_${puarr[PU]}_${1}" -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$sigind $1 >& "${sigind}_${lumarr[lum]}_${1}".txt &;exit"$'\r'
done
return 0
```

Comment: Please explain. `;` waits for the first command before executing the second. Why will this not work?

Comment: `;` delimits two commands, they run one after the other

Comment: Indeed, `;` is exactly what you want. `&` is not.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I redirect the output of the left hand side command into a file and type `exit` as the second command; it says you have `zsh: you have running jobs.` and does not exit. I do not want the job I submitted to be interrupted.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `;`. That means you incorrectly or improperly used `&` somewhere.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Okay I have provided the script where I send the command to the `screen`. I think it is related with `&` as you said.

Comment: @EtanReisner Forgive me, but would a construct like `&;` would not work?

Comment: `&;` is invalid. You cannot have two terminators like that.

Comment: You are trying to stuff two commands into the screen session the second of which is `exit` (to terminate the screen session)? Would it not be easier to just write a script and tell screen to run that (on the `-dmS` line) and then have it automatically just exit when the script dies?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for your suggestion, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Put the command in a script and give that script as an argument to screen. Try `screen -dmS test top` to see what I mean.

Comment: @EtanReisner Actually, I found that writing individual scripts to be really hard since I need 72 of them. Is there a way to have the `screen` terminate after the command it executes finishes?

Comment: That's what it does if that's the command running in the screen window (as opposed to running in the shell running in the screen window) and that's exactly what I was trying to get you to do. I also didn't mean write the scripts ahead of time. Write them in your processing script, chmod +x them, pass them as arguments to screen, then delete them.

Answer (score 3):

for zsh, especially on a mac, it's ;
try it from the terminal

```
sleep 3 ; echo "hello"
```

There will be a 3 seconds delay then it will print hello

Comment: as example `sleep 3 ; echo hello` or `sleep 3 ; echo 'hello'` is better than "hello" because the double quote parses something. (I'm not an expert in shell, but think this worth to be noted)

Answer (score 2):

Use | or & instead of usng || or &&

Comment: Would it also quit if it failed?

Comment: @Vesnog - not sure what you are asking?

Comment: @Vesnog I just saw your update to the question. Is it that you want to run both the screens in parallel?