# How to create a folder and navigate inside the same using one command in mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, command

How to create a folder and navigate inside the same using one command in mac ?
There are two commands to accomplish the task.
But is there a way to do it in single command or single line at least ?

```
mkdir newFolder
cd newFolder
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77295624/how-to-create-custom-command-which-redirect-terminal-to-another-folder-location

Answer (score 0):

Delimit the commands with a ; in one line
[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690518/zsh-executing-two-commands-in-a-row-independent-of-success)